# Twilio Return Transcriptions from a date range

Tags: php, twilio

I have a massive amount of calls transcribed and I would like to return only those from the last month.  I've been trying to pull the data in the same way that a call resource is handled (although there it's "startTime" => "2018-01-01" instead of "datecreated").  I've tried different iterations of datecreated, to no avail.  Has anyone been successful returning transcriptions from a range of dates?

```
    $trans = $client->transcriptions->read(
         array("datecreated" => "2018-01-01")
         );
    foreach ($trans as $transcription){ 
        //do stuff here
        }
```

cheers, lee

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are no filters available on the [list resource for transcriptions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/recording-transcription#transcriptions-list-resource) so you can't search like this.

If you want the most recent month's transcriptions then I recommend loading transcriptions until you find one with a date earlier than the current month.

Alternatively, you could load all the [recordings for that date range](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/recording?code-sample=code-filter-recordings-with-range-match&code-language=php&code-sdk-version=5.x) and then individually fetch the transcription for each one.

Let me know if that helps at all.